# Harware Spec for SCCM Distribution Point

Tags: windows-server-2016, sccm-2012, serverspec

I have looked on Microsoft's documentation about the hardware requirements for a distribution point server to have at every site in the company.

Is the following spec adequate from people's experience?

- 8 CPU cores
- 32 GB ram
- 2TB HDD

Comment: How many clients ? Just the Distribution Point role ?

Comment: Hi thanks, it will have just the DP role, our biggest site has roughly 200 client computers on the network at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/core/plan-design/configs/recommended-hardware#bkmk_ScaleSieSystems) recommends 2 CPU cores and 8 GB of memory.
In my experience, this is more than enough ! In your case, there will be a lot of unused memory.

Pay attention to storage and network performance, though.
I also suggest you evaluate [Peer cache](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/core/plan-design/hierarchy/client-peer-cache) to allow clients to share content with each other.